# Write the algebraic form of :$ (1+j)^{39} \ \text{and} \ (1+j^2)^{39}$ with $j=e^{2iπ/3}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Write the algebraic form of: $$(1+j)^{39} \ \text{and} \ (1+j^2)^{39}$$

Comment: The form $a+jb$ would be my guess. @user272879 Do you know the binomial theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $$\displaystyle j=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}\;,$$ Then $$j^3=e^{i\cdot 2\pi} = \cos 2\pi+i\sin 2\pi =1$$

So we get $$j^3=1\Rightarrow j^3-1^3=0\Rightarrow (j-1)(j^2+j+1) =0$$

So we get $$\displaystyle j^2+j+1 = 0\Rightarrow j+1 = -j^2$$ Bcz $\displaystyle j=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}\neq 1\;$

$(a)\;\;$ Given $$(1+j)^{39} = (-j^2)^{39} = -j^{78} = -(j^3)^{26} = -1$$

Above we get $\displaystyle j^3=1$ and $j^2+j+1=0\Rightarrow 1+j^2=-j$

$(b)\;\; $ Given $$(1+j^2)^{39} = (-j)^{39} = -j^{39} = -(j^3)^{13} = -1$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$1+e^{2i\theta}=1+\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)+2i\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=2\cos(\theta)e^{i\theta}.$$

Then

$$(1+e^{2i\theta})^n=2^n\cos^n(\theta)e^{in\theta}.$$

---

$$2^{39}\left(\frac12\right)^{39}e^{39i\pi/3}=-1,$$
$$2^{39}\left(-\frac12\right)^{39}e^{39\cdot2i\pi/3}=-1.$$